# Happy Holiday Season

Tags: discussion

I realise I am only new on this site, but really enjoyed participating and contributing this last year. I learned a lot, not only from reading questions and answer, but also by asking questions and giving answers. A wonderful hobby it is.

Where ever you are,
Whatever you are celebrating in the Season,
HAM/Amateur radio is a community of friends...

And to my friends and your family, 
I wish you:

Happy Holidays, 
Good Health, 
Good Fortune,
Good Propagation,

and a Happy New Year.

Best Regards,
Edwin - EI2HEB

Answer (score 2):

And you totally didn't do this to try to get a hat here, did you?

Comment: actually, I did not know that I was getting a hat... as it is the festive season, I will wear it ! The message was well meant...

Comment: Sorry, I meant no disrespect, I was only teasing. Still, hope all goes well for yourself, and have a fantastic rest of the year!

Comment: and non taken at all